# Socat specify source port

Tags: netcat, port, socat

How do I specify source port in socat?

In netcat I can simply:

```
nc -u -s 192.168.0.1 -p 8888 192.168.0.2 9999
```

I tried

```
socat udp4:192.168.0.2:9999 STDIN:192.168.0.1:8888
```

It's failed

```
STDIN: wrong number of parameters (2 instead of 0)
```

So how do I do it in socat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the same behavior of `nc -u -s 192.168.0.1 -p 8888 192.168.0.2 9999` using `socat`:

```
$ socat - UDP4:192.168.0.2:9999,bind=192.168.0.1:8888
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, `achieve same behavior`.